# Retrieve the Item ID from the Task List Related Item column

Tags: jquery, caml-query, task-list, json, related-list

Using JSOM, I getting all the task details which are *`not started`*. Using CAML query i got all the column values including related item column from Task list

```
var relateditm = $(this).attr("ows_RelatedItems");
alert(relateditm);
```

The value i got is

```
[{"ItemId":6,"WebId":"da019015-45eb-cd62-83e2-dfb360620954","ListId":"25ca3434-de22-4ccf-8954-6564cc179ea6"}];
```

I want the Item ID alone. How can i retrieve the id from this?

I tried with the below code, but **undefined** error is coming

```
var relateditmid = relateditm[0].ItemId;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your code, the value you get is a **string not an object**.

so the code :
`var relateditmid = relateditm[0].ItemId;` will return the item ID after converting the string **relateditm** to Object using eval funtion.

```
var relateditmObj = eval(relateditm);
var relateditmid = relateditmObj[0].ItemId;
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. If my question is useful. Vote UP :)

Comment: Not a big fan of eval. I would use JSON as the result you are receiving has JSON formatting:
var relatedItem = JSON.parse(relateditm);
var itemID = relatedItem[0].ItemId